# has_and_belongs_to_many association with a genre and book

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two model's Book and Genre. I want to list all the genres that a book might have. For example Fantasy, Romance and so on. Each book has many genre's and i want to add each genre to that specific book when creating it. Would a has_and_belongs_to_many association work better?

I've done what i have below and it works but i have to add each book and genre separately after creating a book and genre.

```
 class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_genre_relations
  has_many :genres, through: :book_genre_relations


 class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_genre_relations
  has_many :books, through: :book_genre_relations


 class BookGenreRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :genre
```

Comment: HABTM associations are implemented as HM:T under the hood (Rails 4). Your approach seems sane to me, is there something particular that's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll benefit from [this article (choosing between `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many):

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a `has_many :through` relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity

---

From a development perspective, there is not much different between `HMT` & `HABTM`. You can achieve what you want using the following in **both** instances:

```
@book   = Book.find params[:id]
@genres = @book.genres
```

The big difference is whether you want to store extra "join" data in your join model (EG "captions" on images etc).

Only with `has_many :through` can you save extra "join" data. `HMT` is basically "dumb" in the sense that you can add objects to the association, but they are just db references.

--

Personally, I would use [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) - you don't have any special need for extra attributes/methods for your `genres`, and as such just want to associate the two:

```
#app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end

#app/models/genre.rb
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

The above gives you the ability to use the `<<` & `.delete` methods which you can use as follows:

```
@book  = Book.find params[:id]
@genre = Genre.find_by name: "Horror"

@book.genres << @genre     if @genre #-> adds to association
@book.genres.delete @genre if @genre #-> removes from association
```

-

You also need to recognize the distinction in schema:

[`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):
[image]

[`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):
[image]

HABTM doesn't have a [`primary_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) or any other attributes in the table. This means it has only the capacity to act as a [`join table`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct (although I would remove the word Relation from that model, it's not really needed).

You said:
"...but i have to add each book and genre separately after creating a book and genre."

but I think you meant:
"...but i have to add a book/genre record to the relation table after creating a book and genre."

So if you mean that you are doing something like this:

```
my_book = Book.create(<attributes>)
my_genre = Genre.create(<attributes>)
BookGenreRelation.create(book: my_book, genre: my_genre)
```

then you are also correct, that is how you create the link between the 2 objects.

If you meant something else, please post the code you are using to create the objects.

To answer your question about using a 'has_and_belongs_to_many' my advice would be no. The way you have it now is quite standard Rails approach.

If you want to know why my advice is no, [read this](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/).